# No install candidate for ghostscript in node:16 docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, ghostscript

My nodejs project depends on ghostscript and imagemagick and on the build step for these dependencies I get this message:

```sh
Step 5/7 : RUN apt-get install -y imagemagick ghostscript
 ---> Running in 3c39769c2f1a
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package ghostscript is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
E: Package 'ghostscript' has no installation candidate
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y imagemagick ghostscript' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

This step does not fail on an ubuntu container but i'm trying not to use that because i'm having issues with the nodejs package from apt-get
It's my understanding that apt-get looks through all the repositories it knows about to find an install candidate. So if in the node:16 image it doesn't know where to find ghostscript I need to add it to my list of apt repositories? If that is so, how would I go about doing that and how would I find which apt repository I need to add?

Comment: With the very partial info you gave, [I can't reproduce your problem](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/df20f8f446896617ba93d27c5bed43c6). You are showing build step 5/7 which clearly shows you have already messed with the initial apt repositories from the original image (see warning messages). We have no idea what was run before that step and how it can influence the result.

Comment: Have you previously run `apt-get update`?  I believe failing to do it at all could cause this issue; generally you need to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single `RUN` line to avoid some potential issues around Docker's build cache.

Comment: Good point, I'll give it a try

Comment: That did it! thanks David!